# WPF / XAML - Can text be auto sized?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, graphics, fonts

For a fixed size wrappable text area, is there any way to make the font size as large as possible based on the amount of text?

For example, if you have a 500x500 area with the text "Hello", the font size would be really big.  But if you have a paragraph of text the font size would be smaller to fit into the area.

I have looked at Viewbox but can't see that it could work with wrappable text.

ANY xaml or code that could do this would help (doesn't have to be a specific control).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking is more complex than it sounds, but I'll give you an idea:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBox x:Name="text" Text="this is some text and some more text I don't see any problems..." DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextChanged="text_TextChanged"/>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding ElementName=tb, Path=FontSize}"/>
    <Border Name="bd" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock Name="tb" Text="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

And in code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    RecalcFontSize();
    tb.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(tb_SizeChanged);
}

void tb_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RecalcFontSize();
}

private void RecalcFontSize()
{
    if (tb == null) return;
    Size constraint = new Size(tb.ActualWidth, tb.ActualHeight);
    tb.Measure(constraint);
    while (tb.DesiredSize.Height < tb.ActualHeight)
    {
        tb.FontSize += 1;
        tb.Measure(constraint);
    }
    tb.FontSize -= 1;
}

private void text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RecalcFontSize();
}
```

Try it, drag it around, change the text...

Comment: It works for (200,200), unfortunately it does not work for (440,330).

If you try that constraint you'll notice the bottom line is clipped off.  I have a screen shot and sample app if that helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try now. Mind you this is just a lead, there's probably a better way to reach the optimal font size without incrementing it 1 by 1...

Comment: With this last revision it seems to work perfectly for all cases - Thanks.  It looks like working with the height only was the key.  I'm now going to work on a custom control so it can easily be added to Xaml without changing the Window code behind.  I have marked your answer correct.

Comment: I'll be interested in getting that control when you're done with it, if there's no commercial considerations that is :)

Comment: Not at all - I'll try to get it published with binary and source code to share for anyone who might find it use full -

Comment: Still doesn't work - add this text to the sample above "problematic stuff".  When narrowing the window the word "problematic" breaks into separate letters rather than downsizing the text.  WPF cannot be tamed!

Comment: Is there a way to set a max limit of the font size and once it's reached, vertically align text to center? If I set tb.VerticalAlignment property in XAML or code, the window does not load.